# Validate a list of inputs email Angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have this code in Angular 8, where it shows me a list of inputs like the image attached.

The problem that I have is I have to validate the Syntax of emails when I click in a button "Complete" and also change the color of input if this is invalid:

[image]

If it was just one field, I would use a formGroup to validate but I don't know how to validate a list of email fields.

any help please.

this is the code:

```
    // TS

this.admins = [{first_name: "", last_name: "", email: ""}]

public addAdmin(): void{
    this.admins.push({first_name: "", last_name: "", email: ""});
}

// HTML
<div class="row adminTableGetStarted" *ngFor="let ad of admins">
    <div class="colThree input">
        <input name="first-name-admin" type="text" placeholder="" 
        [(ngModel)]="ad.first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="colThree input">
        <input name="last-name-admin" type="text" placeholder="" 
        [(ngModel)]="ad.last_name"  />
    </div>
    <div class="colThree input">
        <input name="email-admin" type="email" placeholder="" 
        [(ngModel)]="ad.email" 
        pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="addAdminPlus" (click)="addAdmin()">
+ Add Administrator
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's a bit of a learning curve, I believe Angular's `FormArray` would be the best fit for your situation. The idea is that you would setup a new `FormArray` where you can push data like a normal array, but it also includes some built-in validation.

I would recommend learning the following starting from basic to more complex:

1. Learn the basics of reactive forms using a `FormControl` example.
2. Learn how to setup a `FormGroup` that contains multiple/different `FormControl`s.
3. Learn how to setup a `FormGroup` that contains a `FormArray` holding multiple/similar `FormControl`s.

Once you understand the above, setting up validation for email is quite simple. When you define the `FormControl` for each email, you can add Angular's built-in validation.

`new FormControl('', Validators.email)`

References:

- Reactive Forms Video Overview (including FormArray Example): https://youtu.be/JeeUY6WaXiA
- Reactive Forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
- Reactive Form Validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms